# SQLLite (Синтаксис WHERE и использование JOIN)

Tags: sql

Дана таблица (House_EKB) с шириной (Width) и длиной (length) жилых участков (Number_of_House). Как найти все номера домов, у которых ширина больше средней ширины всех домов, но не используя подзапрос, скорее всего с помощью JOIN?

Пробовала сделать через `WHERE House_EKB1.width > AVG (House_EKB2.width)`. Но SQL выдает ошибку неверного использования функции. Возможно ли использовать WHERE в синтасисе с другими функциями?

Comment: Попробуйте HAVING вместо WHERE

Comment: HAVING же работает только c GROUP BY, а если проводить группировку, то будут объединяться нужные строки. Хотя можно попробовать группировать по id. Спасибо

Comment: CTE не является подзапросом. Потому решением будет получение средней ширины в CTE и получение нужной выборки в основном запросе.